# Cannot type with keyboard without enabling onscreen keyboard

Tags: keyboard, onscreen-keyboard

I'm encountering a strange issue where I can type my user password at log in time. I can also type in the activities search bar. However, when using apps, I'm unable to type with my keyboard unless the onscreen keyboard is enabled.

For example, when using terminal, the app behaves as if it is not in focus, and therefore cannot receive keyboard input. Apparently enabling the onscreen keyboard allows the app to gain focus, but then I can type with my real keyboard making the onscreen keyboard redundant.

Any hints of settings to adjust, software/drivers to check would be great!

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Lastest Ubuntu 22.04